# Adding specific words to a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add words to a class file that I can set a certain style for the rest of the document

eg:

I want to set the word "the" to a class called cross

CSS

```
.cross {
    font-style:italic
}
```

What would happen:
"*the* man walked to *the* shops."

Is this possible to do? Or is there another way to style the word "the" everytime it is used throughout the document?

Comment: The word 'the' should be in some sort of <span> with class cross, I imagine.

Comment: @TJ, Yep, it's exactly the same condition in that question, Use javascript to achieve that. Some sort of highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
   var text = 'the';
    $('*').html( function ( i, html ) {
        var regexp, replacement;
        regexp = RegExp( '(' + text + ')', 'gi' );
        replacement = '<span class="cross">$1</span>';
        return html.replace( regexp, replacement );
    });
```

Comment: I have added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neelsg/Dz7SP/) to show that this does work

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through each word something like this:

```
var tokens = text.split(" ");
for(var i=0; i < tokens.length; i++){
    if(tokens[i] == "the"){
        tokens[i] = "<span class='cross'>the</span>";
    }
}
$(elem).html(tokens.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4MrCV/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="mytext">the man walked to the shops not their shop.</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $t = $("#mytext");
$t.html($t.text().replace(/the /gi,"<span class='cross'>$&</span>"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is nice but you should modify it to exclude text which contains `the` in them like `there`, `their` etc..

Answer (score -2):

Generally you would use a `span` to style a word

```
<p><span class="cross">the</span> man walked to <span class="cross">the</span> shops.</p>
```

Comment: *style the word "the" everytime it is used throughout the **document***